# the pointer of the entire array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory

```
    int main(){
        int a[][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
        int (*ptr)[3]=a;
        printf(" %d",(*ptr)[1]) ;
    }
```

I know that the variable `ptr` is a pointer of the first 1d array of type `int`, in other words the variable `ptr` will store the the address of the first 3 integers, first let's suppose that the base address of `a` is `1000` so as I think this 2d array will be stored in the memory in this form:

```
elements:                  |    1     |    2     |    3     ||    4     |    5     |    6     |
addressed of each element: |   1000   | 1004     | 1008     ||   1012   | 1016     | 1020     |
                           ---------------------------------||---------------------------------
addressed of each array:                1000                              1012
```

So `ptr` will store the value `1000` which is the address of the first array. And that means `*ptr` or `(*ptr)[0]` will give me the address of the first element, and `*ptr+1`  or `((*ptr)[1])` will give me the address of the second element and so on.

So as I understand `*ptr[1]` will give the address of the second element, and not it's value.

But from the output it seem that I am wrong. So I want to know what is the problem in my process.

Comment: the output is 2

Comment: I hope you see that you're not really initializing a 2D array, or rather - an array of arrays.

Comment: no ,i did, because even if i did not use brackets for the arrays  inside the original brackets, the compiler will see that i have a number of arrays inside the brackets because i said to hem  i will create 3 columns for each array  ,so the compiler  will see 6 columns wich is 3 columns plus 3 columns and he will understand that i have two array of three elements for each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct until this part:

> And that means `*ptr` or `(*ptr)[0]` will give me the address of the first element

`*ptr` will do that. `(*ptr)[0]` will de-reference the array pointer and then dereference the resulting array, giving you the value of the first item, `1`.

Similarly, `(*ptr)[1])` will first give you an array and then the second item in that array, `2`.

> So as I understand *ptr[1] will give the address of the second element, and not it's value.

No, since `[]` has higher precedence than `*`, `ptr[1]` will first give you (the address of) the second array. Then you dereference that and you'll get the the value of the first item in the second array,  `4`.

The key here is that once you de-reference a pointer to an array, you end up with an array - behaving just like any array would in terms of "array decay" etc.

---

Best practices:

- Do not de-reference array pointers with `*` if you can avoid it. `ptr[0][0]` is much less ambiguous. That syntax is the whole point of using array pointers in this case to begin with.
- Avoid sloppy initializer lists like `int a[][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6};`. C allows it but it is bad style and mutes some possibilities of diagnostics. Instead this should have been `int a[][3]={ {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };` which as a bonus is also readable, self-documenting code.

Comment: okey so ,can i say (*ptr)[0]=*(*ptr+0)?

Comment: @anas Yes, `(*ptr)[0]` is the same as `*((*ptr)+0)` which is the same as `*(*ptr+0)` which is the same as `*(*ptr)` which is the same as `**ptr`. And it is also the same as `ptr[0][0]`.

Comment: @anas `something[n]` is by definition 100% equivalent to `*( (something) + (n) )` and that has nothing to do with pointers to arrays as such.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's a good idea to enable compiler warnings. Then you will be informed about missing braces in the initializer. Here is a slightly cleaned up version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
    int (*ptr)[3] = a;
    printf("%d\n", (*ptr)[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

If you run it you will get the output "2". This is because `*ptr` is the first element of the array `a`, which itself is an array, and `(*ptr)[1]` is therefor the second element in this contained array which is 2.

[image: pointer diagram]

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the expression used in the call of `printf`

```
printf(" %d",(*ptr)[1]) ;
```

For starters the pointer `ptr` points to the first element of the type `int[3]` of the two-dimensional array .

```
int (*ptr)[3]=a;
```

That is due to the initializer list

```
int a[][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

the two-dimensional array has two elements of the type `int[3]`.

So dereferencing the pointer `*ptr` you get an lvalue of the type `int[3]` that is a one-dimensional array. Then to this array there is applied the subscript operator `( *ptr )[1]` that yields the second element of the one-dimensional array.

So the value `2` will be outputted.

> And that means *ptr or (*ptr)[0] will give me the address of the first
> element

The expression `*ptr` and `( *ptr )[0]`  are two entities of different types.`The expression`*ptr`yields lvalue of the type`int[3]` , Use din expressions it is in turn can be implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element of the obtained array.

The expression `( *ptr )[0]` yields the first scalar element of the obtained array of the type `int`.

> So as I understand *ptr[1] will give the address of the second
> element, and not it's value.

The expression `ptr[1]` yields the second element of the type `int[3]` of the two-dimensional array  In this expression `*ptr[1]` the obtained object of the type `int[3]` is implicitly converted to pointer of the type `int *` and dereferencing the pointer yields the first element of the type `int` of the second element of the two-dimensional array.

To make in more clear consider how the subscript operator is evaluated.

For example the expression `ptr[0]` is equivalent to `*( ptr + 0 )` that in turn is equivalent to `*ptr`.

The expression `(*ptr)[1]` is equivalent to `ptr[0][1]`.

The expression `*ptr[1]` is equivalent to `*(ptr[1] )` that in turn is equivalent to  `ptr[1][0]`.

In general the expression `ptr[i][j]` can be rewritten in several ways. For example

```
( *( ptr + i ) )[j]
*( *( ptr + i ) + j )
*( ptr[i] + j )
```